# Lion: background of the login screen

Tags: macos

I just updated to Lion and I'm wondering why the background of the locked screen (login screen) seem to be different everytime I look at it: it is either the grey texture, the default desktop background or a plain black background.

Why isn't it the same background all the time ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are logging in fresh, it is grey linen.

If you are waking from sleep or display sleep without a screen saver enabled, it is the desktop background.

If you are waking from a screen saver, it is the screen saver itself.

Finally, if you are waking from display sleep or sleep after a screen saver has been ended by display sleep or sleep, it is a black background.

There does not appear to be a way to change this, but keep your eye on apps like Secrets.  If anyone's going to figure it out, it's them.

Comment: What do you mean "screen saver has finished" ?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear.  I've edited the post.

Comment: For me, sometimes its linen; other times its the galaxy background; and my desktop background is set to a solid grey color. No consistent behavior of the login background.